# Json objects; wanting to print only the div contains the word entered in search when btn is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, json

The task is that when the user writes for example "Tyskland" as input and presses the "sokLand" btn, only the objects/divs containing "Tyskland" will appear on the page. Until now I only managed to print all objects when the "alleLand" btn is clicked. Any ideas?

```
<body>
    <div>
        <h3 id="header">Mitt feriested</h3>
        <label>Land:
            <input id="land" type="text">
        </label>
        <input id="sokLand" class="landBtn" type="button" value="Søk etter land">
        <input id="alleLand" class="landBtn" type="button" value="Velg alle destinasjoner">
    </div>   

    <div id="land_list"></div>

    <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>

        var feriestederJSON = { landliste: [
            {"land": "Tyskland", 
             "by": "Munchen", 
             "bildeAvBy": "pictures/munchen.jpg"
            },
            {"land": "Tyskland", 
             "by": "Berlin", 
             "bildeAvBy": "pictures/berlin.jpg"
            },
            {"land": "Spania", 
             "by": "Barcelona", 
             "bildeAvBy": "pictures/barcelona.jpg"
            },
            {"land": "Spania", 
             "by": "Palma", 
             "bildeAvBy": "pictures/palma.jpg"
            },
            {"land": "Norge", 
             "by": "Oslo", 
             "bildeAvBy": "pictures/oslo.jpg"
            },
            {"land": "Norge", 
             "by": "Bergen", 
             "bildeAvBy": "pictures/bergen.jpg"
            },
        ]};

        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#alleLand").click(function() {
                var antallLand = feriestederJSON.landliste.length;
                var output_html ="";

                for(var i = 0; i < antallLand; i++){
                    var land = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].land;
                    var by = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].by;
                    var bildeAvBy = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].bildeAvBy;

                    output_html += '<div id="element">' + land + ': ' + by + ' <img src="' + bildeAvBy + '" /></div>';
                }

            document.querySelector("#land_list").innerHTML = output_html;
            });

            $("#sokland").click(function() {

                var antallLand = feriestederJSON.landliste.length;
                var output_html ="";

                var searchText = $("#land").val();

                for(var i = 0; i < antallLand; i++){

                    var land = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].land;

                    if ((land.search(searchText)) > -1) {

                        var land = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].land;
                        var by = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].by;
                        var bildeAvBy = feriestederJSON.landliste[i].bildeAvBy;

                        output_html += '<div id="element">' + land + ': ' + by + ' <img src="' + bildeAvBy + '" /></div>';
                    }
                    document.querySelector("#land_list").innerHTML = output_html;
                }

            });
        });


</script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your `$("#sokLand")` `click` event like this

```
          $("#sokLand").click(function () {
                var antallLand = feriestederJSON.landliste.length;
                var output_html = "";
                var searchText = $("#land").val();
                var searchedJson = [];
                $.each(feriestederJSON.landliste, function (index, item) {
                    if (item.land == searchText) {
                        searchedJson.push(item);
                    }
                });
                for (var i = 0; i < searchedJson.length; i++) {
                    var land = searchedJson[i].land;
                    var by = searchedJson[i].by;
                    var bildeAvBy = searchedJson[i].bildeAvBy;
                    output_html += '<div id="element">' + land + ': ' + by + ' <img src="' + bildeAvBy + '" /></div>';
                }
                document.querySelector("#land_list").innerHTML = output_html;
            });
```